# Is there any way to compile gcc to support a single language?

Tags: java, gcc, jvm, virtual-machine

I want to compile gcc so i can use the mips R2000 microprocessor compiler inorder to use [NestedVM](http://nestedvm.ibex.org/) a way of targeting any executable to the java vm; but I don't want it to compile the modules for other languages than mine or architectures other than the R2000 or the Mips family.

Comment: And what does the gcc compiler directive documentation tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html

You need the --enable-languages option to configure.

The procedure appears to have changed since I did sysop work.  I have not tried this personally.